# How do i detect a symbol such as ® in a div and then apply a style just to the symbol? jquery?

Tags: jquery

I am learning jQuery as I read all of the post when I need help.

In that case, I though I should first detect if inside the div there is the ® ( `&reg;` )( registered trademark ) and then somehow use the addClass ?

Answer (score 3):

I have just tried this out, and it seems that jQuery won't pick up on html entities such as `&reg;` or `&amp;`, so you have to actually use the symbol, which works.

```
$("div:contains(®)").addClass("newclass");
```

Hope that helps.